# Typemock unit tests are marked as "Not Active"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, typemock-isolator

My company is adopting typemock for unit test coverage.  In the navigator almost all of our tests are marked as "Ignored" with the reason "Project is not in build configuration"

However my projects are being built in this solution and I can run the tests manually but I have no way of running through all of the tests with a single click

Comment: Hi! I'm working at Typemock. Can you write to support@typemock.com to investigate and fix your issue?

Comment: @Eva just did, text from the question